How to enable Dataverse Link to MS Fabric? - Power BI Premium missing
I have enabled Microsoft Fabric Trial
I have dataverse table. I select Analyze and then Link to Microsoft Fabric.
It complains that I'm missing Power BI Premium licence.
When I click Premium of Power BI workspace settings, I cannot select Microsoft Fabric Trial.
How to make Fabric Link working?

Hello
You cannot use Power BI premium feature with MS Fabric Trial licence.
You need to have at least a F64 capacity workspace to use Power BI premium capacity or to have a Power BI premium per user licence linked to your account.
